# Conditions which guarantee that two points do not collide?

Tags: kinematics

Consider two material points $A$ and $B$, with $B$ following $A$, moving with linear motion at constant speed and with $v_A<v_B$ (which means that, excluding possible decelerations, $B$ and $A$ will collide). I'm trying to understand the difference between two conditions to impose to have as a consequence that $A$ and $B$ do not collide.

$1.$ $B$ has the same speed of $A$ when it meets $A$ (i.e. $B$ decreases its velocity until it reaches the speed of $A$ exactly when it is in the same position of $A$).

$2.$ $B$ has zero speed when it meets $A$

I'm asking because I saw these conditions in the solutions of some exercises and I don't understand how these two conditions can imply that $A$ and $B$ do not collide, since it is explicitly said that $B$ actually reaches/meets $A$. Can someone help me to understand what does these condition actually imply and what are the differencese between $1.$ and $2.$?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Time frame and distance between A and B possibly?

Comment: Look up the term "asymptotic".

Answer (score 0):

A collision is an event in which two or more
bodies exert forces on each other for a
relatively short time.
Collision is short-duration interaction
between two bodies or more than two
bodies simultaneously causing change in
motion of bodies involved due to internal
forces acted between them during this.
Collisions involve forces (there is a change
in velocity). The magnitude of the velocity
difference at impact is called the closing
speed.

## Case 1:

Since both had no speed difference , they could not exert any force on each other.
No,force no collision.
Consider it like a big box was sliding in space with uniform velocity.You suddenly cut it from middle. Now, they would still touch each other but  they won't be colliding.

## Case 2:

As explained above touching does not necessarily mean exerting force, you can understand why when B had 0 speed it exerted no force.